# Restore Purchases with Xamarin.InAppPurchases on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I'm using the Xamarin.InAppPurchases plugin for iOS. Basically, the call to InAppPurchaseManager.RestorePreviousPurchases is not triggering the login prompt if the user is not logged into iTunes. I looked into the disassembly and saw that it was basically running some checks and then calling the internal Restore Purchase. I modified my code to this. Does anyone know the implications of calling RestoreCompletedTransactions with and without the string name identifier? When called like this, the prompt comes up.

```
//Forced to call this in order to trigger login
SKPaymentQueue.DefaultQueue.RestoreCompletedTransactions();

//Redundant, but I don't know the implications of removing it 
inAppPurchaseManager.RestorePreviousPurchases();
```

The top comment here by Tom Glanville seems to indicate that he is having the same issue. https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inapppurchase

EDIT--  I believe it is a bug in Xamarin. I've posted the bug here: [Bugzilla 53100](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53100) I put in a workaround which involves calling the receipt API. It seems to work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround I have put in to get around the bug.

```
//Forced to call this in order to trigger login
//Get a receipt
var receiptRequest = new SKReceiptRefreshRequest();
receiptRequest.Init();
receiptRequest.Delegate = new ReceiptRequestDelegate(inAppManager);
receiptRequest.Start();

//Use this to trigger login
public class ReceiptRequestDelegate : SKRequestDelegate
{
    private InAppPurchaseManager inAppManager;

    public ReceiptRequestDelegate(InAppPurchaseManager iapm)
    {
        inAppManager = iapm;
    }

    public override void RequestFinished(SKRequest request)
    {
        //Now call restore purchases
        inAppManager.RestorePreviousPurchases();
    }

    public override void RequestFailed(SKRequest request, NSError error)
    {
        //Handle request failed
    }
}
```

As for my question about the implications of calling RestoreCompletedTransactions with and without the applicationUsername, it seems that will affect some of the information in the transaction you can store on the server. It lets you identify the user with their local username, since in iTunes it will only associate it with their iTunes account. You can learn more here [Detecting Irregular Activity](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/RequestPayment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW6).